# Eigenvector and eigenvalue with cvBlobsLib

Tags: opencv, blob, detection

I use [cvBlobsLib](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib) for blob detection. At the moment I need large and small eigenvalues and corresponding eingenvectors. All what I could find in the documentation of library are `CBlobGetMajorAxisLength` and `CBlobGetMinorAxisLength`. If I am right: first gives me the large eigenvalue and the second - the small eigenvalue. But now I also need eigenvectors which I could not find in the library. Maybe you know which function can give me those values or how I can calculate them with this library. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try moments. From there you can form a covariance matrix which correspond to the eigen vectors and eigen values.